# emacsclient -t hangs

Tags: emacs, xterm

I'm trying to use emacs (23.2.1) in daemon mode. I started it as `emacs --daemon` and that works just fine. But whenever I try `emacsclient -t somefile` I first get a line of garbage (e.g., `1;25C2;'), then the file is displayed (with emacs's mode line), but I can't do anything. It hangs; cursor movement keys don't work; C-x # doesn't work; the only thing I can do is open another console and kill the process.

If I start emacs normally (by clicking on a launcher on the panel, or just running `emacs`) with `(server-start)` in the config, `emacsclient file` works just fine (i.e., loads the file in the graphical emacs instance). If I start emacs normally but use `emacsclient -t file`, I get the same problem with it hanging.

I'm using Debian 6/Xfce, kernel 2.6.32-5-686. `$TERM` is xterm, maybe that needs to be changed to something else? Is there anything else that's a likely culprit? I don't want to post my entire emacs config here because it's extensive, but if you really want to look through it it's [here on github](https://github.com/ibrunton/emacs).

Thanks

Comment: Works For Me™. Does it work for you if you start Emacs with `emacs -q` (to skip your `.emacs`)? If not, what about `emacs -Q` (skips all installed packages)? What terminal emulator are you running `emacsclient -t` in, and does using another emulator make a difference? I suspect Emacs is sending an escape sequence that expects a response and not getting it, but the important data is the character before the `1`, which doesn't get displayed. Run `strace -o emacs.strace -s9999 emacs --daemon` and post the resulting `emacs.strace` somewhere (it may be huge).

Comment: @Gilles: The emulator is whatever default ships with Debian 6/Xfce4, simply called "Terminal Emulator". In that, `emacs -q --daemon` doesn't fix it, but `emacs -Q --daemon` does. In LXTerminal, the -q option works fine; with just `emacs --daemon` in LXTerminal, `emacsclient -t` doesn't actually hang (I can still C-x # to exit) but it doesn't give me a cursor or allow me to actually do anything. Working on the strace thing now.

Comment: @Gilles: http://ironhaq.tumblr.com/post/4803854323/strace-o-emacs-strace-s9999-emacs-daemon

Comment: @Wolf: The trace is missing the good bits. My fault, can you do it again with `strace -f -o emacs.strace -s9999 emacs --daemon`? Also, to find out what this mysterious “Terminal Emulator” is, please run `ps $PPID` in it. Also, since the bug is apparently triggered by an installed package, run `dpkg -S /etc/emacs*/site-start.d` to get the list.

Comment: @Gilles: The terminal is "xfce4-terminal". The `dpkg` command gives: `a2ps, dictionaries-common, emacsen-common, git: /etc/emacs/site-start.d \ emacs23-common: /etc/emacs23/site-start.d` (that \ represents a newline). And the updated strace out put is here: http://www.friendpaste.com/6MzrccvkziCBxUhGCrzgn8

Comment: @Wolf: The main Emacs process is waiting for a client to connect, did you post the trace before running emacsclient? But I now realize the interesting bits should be in what emacsclient does. So: `strace -f -s9999 -o emacsclient.strace emacsclient -t somefile` (we'll get there eventually!).

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, that strace was before running emacsclient. Here's the trace on emacsclient: http://friendpaste.com/5nXokwYNJQdsMsDf09Knlk . Strangely, though, this morning it's working just fine. Maybe something I commented out of my emacs config was the problem; or maybe it's just a fluke and it'll go back to misbehaving. But do let me know if you see anything significant in the strace. The only thing I did differently this time was run `emacs --daemon &`, i.e., with the & on the end, which I had thought might be redundant for a `--daemon` but decided to try anyway.

Comment: @Wolf: There's no useful information in the trace if it doesn't exhibit the problem. I'm glad you can use Emacs again. Be sure to come back if you manage to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for all your help! I just wish I knew what we did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `man emacsclient`, I see that `-t` is the same as `-nw` and `--tty`, and they all do: `open a new Emacs frame on the current terminal`. If you just drop the `-t`, or replace it with `-c, --create-frame
              create a new frame instead of trying to use the current Emacs frame` it should work. I have `(server-start)`  in my `'emacs`, and my `$EDITOR` is set to "emacsclient", and it works for me. (Ubuntu 11.10, Gnu Emacs 23.2.1)

Comment: The original poster obviously wants the `-t` functionality.

Comment: having `(server-start)` in .emacs file wouldn't let to start multiple emacs daemon(s) each time an emacsclient opens a file?